# Table Relationship Issues

Tags: ms-access

I need some assistance linking 2 tables.

I have a products table and an additives table. Some products have 1-3 different additives in them.

I have them linked by their codes but they aren't showing as linked like my other tables. Is it because I have several different Additive Codes under 1 product?

Can someone point me in the right direction here! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help, as well as make your app more flexible, to have a intermediate table which has only the Product Code of the parent item and a field for the Additive Code.  Then you link your tblProducts to the Product Code in this intermediate table, and you link the Additive Codes in the intermediate table to the tblAdditives.Product Code field.  This should provide the links you are seeking, as well as allowing an unlimited Additives.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. Table designing is a very critical stage so please carefully use the best approach as per your requirement.

1. Use an associative table as suggested by @Dale, this would be the best approach.
2. You can create a multivalued field which will allow storing more than one Additive codes in the same field. In case your additive code list is limited then you can go in this way and the advantage you have is easily displaying all values in reports.

[Guide to multivalued fields](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guide-to-multivalued-fields-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31)